# How to get both Command Prompt and PowerShell in the Win-X menu?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I would like to have both Command Prompt AND PowerShell listed in the Windows-X menu (the same one that opens when you right-click on the Start button).

I have found guides explaining how to switch between one or the other, but I'd really like to have both these options listed in that menu at the same time.

Note: This question is not about the right-click Context menu or other menus. This is about the menu that shows when you press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> or when you right-click on the Start Menu. It's sometimes called the Power User menu or the Command menu.

Comment: I do not think you can adjust this menu.  I put Command and Command Admin on the menu and then get Power Shell from the Start Menu when I need it.

Answer (score 0):

The right click menu? You can add or remove whatever you want from it.

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/add-the-command-prompt-to-the-windows-explorer-right-click-menu/

You can also pin the shortcuts to both the Start Menu and the Taskbar.

From PowerShell, you can type in `cmd` and you'll be taken to the command prompt from within PowerShell.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is the Context Menu that you pointed us to.  I cannot find anything that allows change to the Start Button Right Click menu .

Comment: Ohhhh I understand. Start Menu in the title and right click menu in the question lacks clarity, but I see what you mean. And yeah, if that is the menu described, don't know how to edit it either. Researching...

Comment: Found it. There's a YouTube video of the process. Looks legit. Working on a test to make sure it works as described. https://www.htguk.com/get-back-control-panel-winx-menu-instead-settings-windows-10-creators-update-customize-way-really/

Comment: That looks like a good, if involved solution @JimDiroffII. To make it into an answer, you'll need to include all of that information into the body of your answer. Include the link for reference and attribution, but the answer itself will need to be posted here to be valid.